# Azure devops rest api, how to modify a value

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to learn how to use Azure DevOps rest API.

Is there a way I can modify a certain given value? for example here I want to change the outcome of the first test point with the ID **70155** from **active** to **Pass test** using the rest API:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Points - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/points/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) Rest API:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/Suites/{suiteId}/points/{pointIds}?api-version=6.1-preview.2
```

Body:

```
{
  "outcome": "Passed"
}
```

Comment: I tried it with postman (https://dev.azure.com/fodservices/Training%20projects/_apis/test/Plans/70152/Suites/70154/points/70155?api-version=6.1-preview.2) and the result is 401Unauthorized is there something im doing wrong?

Comment: You need to authorize... see here how: https://sanderh.dev/call-Azure-DevOps-REST-API-Postman/

Comment: Thnx, i did that now the error is 403 forbidden and the "message": "You are not authorized to access this API. Please contact your project administrator", ... did i do it right but i dont have access? because i can change the outcome when im on the azure devops manually

Comment: I managed to get the full list using GET https://dev.azure.com/fodservices/Training%20projects/_apis/test/Plans/70152/Suites/70154/TestPoint?api-version=6.1-preview.2 .. do u think i should use TestPoint instead of Point? if so how do i update the outcome now of the test point

Comment: i tried to change the outcome to passed using PATCH https:// dev.azure.com/f odservices/Training%20projects/_apis/ testplan/Plans/70152/Suites/70154/TestPoint?api-version=6.1-preview.2 and the error message is :     "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: TestPointUpdateParams",